# How do I easily and cleanly update an image in Kivy widget from python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, kivy, kivy-language

Firstly, this is a large piece of code so I will try to simplify it for the sake of this question. I have a Kivy Language script which has a root widget, with an action bar and boxlayout. The code's general structure goes a bit like this (I do not believe this is required for answering this question but here it is anyway): `Root > MenuBarWidg > BoxLayout > Image + Other buttons/labels...`.

Now, here is what my widget looks like in kivy (for the boxlayout):

```
<DisplayPhoto>:
    Image:
        id: image_display
        allow_strech: True
        #StringProperty in the class
        source: root.image_path

    Button:
```

Inside my python script:

```py
class DisplayPhoto(BoxLayout):
    image_path = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DisplayPhoto, self).__init__(self)
        self.image_path = 'reload.png'

    #this is called from another class on a button press
    def update(self):
        self.image_path = 'new_image_path.png'
```

Upon calling update in the python script, nothing happens. I have tried `print(self.image_path)` which displays `new_image_path.png`, but it is also a string - not a kivy object.

I have tried things such as updating the `source` by calling the `id` etc but got nowhere with that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is how you call that `update()` method.

Please refer to the following code

One way of doing it:

main.py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 0)

Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MainView (BoxLayout):
    image_source = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.image_source = 'pic1.png'


class AnotherClass(BoxLayout):

    def change_image(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.ids['my_image'].source = 'pic2.png'


class ImageChangeApp (App):

    def build(self):
        return MainView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageChangeApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```py
<MainView>:
    Image:
        id: my_image
        source: root.image_source
    AnotherClass:


<AnotherClass>:
    Button:
        text: 'Change picture'
        on_release: root.change_image()
```

Another way of doing it is using event dispatcher

main.py:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 0)

Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MainView (BoxLayout):
    pass


class DisplayPhoto(BoxLayout):
    image_path = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DisplayPhoto, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.image_path = 'pic1.png'
        self.register_event_type('on_image_path')

    def on_image_path(self, instance, val):
        print(instance)
        print(val)
        self.image_path = val


class AnotherClass(BoxLayout):

    def change_image(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.ids['display_photo'].dispatch('on_image_path', self, 'pic2.png')


class ImageChangeApp (App):

    def build(self):
        return MainView()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageChangeApp().run()
```

main.kv

```py
<MainView>:

    DisplayPhoto:
        id: display_photo

    AnotherClass:

<DisplayPhoto>:
    Image:
        source: root.image_path

<AnotherClass>:
    Button:
        text: 'Change picture'
        on_release: root.change_image()
```

Comment: Sorry for only just seeing this so late... The second example with the event dispatcher worked like a charm. Thank you!